# How to integrate CKEditor with Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, ckeditor, readonly

This is a bit tricky because Heroku uses a Read-only Filesystem across their Dyno Grid.

Which means when trying to install ckeditor remotely, I get an error :

```
heroku rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Read-only file system - /disk1/home/slugs/362142_8858805_b85c-f2f3955d-f087-4bc4-8b1b-b6e898403a10/mnt/public/javascripts/ckcustom.js
```

ckcustom.js is a config file to manage your meta settings for ckeditor. I was wondering if anyone else had these troubles, and what they did to get around them?

Comment: Have you tried any of these steps? http://www.joshcrews.com/blog/using-heroku-to-host-your-rails-cms if so, can you post the migration file that's failing?

Comment: seems like what he's doing is extracting all the files from the plugin and manually embedding them in the application itself. but wouldn't it still write temp files in my public/ dir? I have at the very least read twenty times over the rails-ckeditor repository.

Comment: Did you get this working?  Getting errors myself doing a db:migrate on heroku with a ckeditor app

Comment: Yes to fix this, run the server as production on your local, then add commit those new files to heroku. You're all set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this error occured was because Heroku ran on my production environment. Because CKEditor is being set up on a new environment, it attempts to write a bunch of files. Because Heroku is a read-only file system it aborts this process. In order to bypass this error :

On your local machine, perform this :

```
rails s -e production
```

View your site, CKeditor will write those files for production env.

```
git add .
git commit -m "added files to Production for Heroku"
git push heroku master
```

It should now!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you're not just committing it to git and pushing it to heroku along with the rest of your source?  I've never had to configure CKeditor with heroku, but that ought to work AFAIK.

Comment: i am committing it to git, and pushing it to heroku, yes. then after i do that i perform `rake db:migrate`, and thats where it fails, and this ticket takes up.

Answer (score 0):

A cheap way to do it is to go to easy_ckeditor/init.rb and comment out the check_and_install:

```
#require 'ckeditor_file_utils'
#CkeditorFileUtils.check_and_install
```

Comment: That sounds ghetto-fantastic!

Comment: It passes the tests, so it's quality ghetto. :-)

Comment: where is this file located.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was the following:

Make sure to

```
bundle update ckeditor
```

and then, add these lines to `config/application.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
```

This was answered in this other stack overflow thread: [Problems with ckeditor running on production Rails application with Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777316/problems-with-ckeditor-running-on-production-rails-application-with-heroku)