# rails heroku issue pushing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, heroku

when i go to my heroku url after i do git push heroku i get an error telling me to check my logs. here is my logs

what am i doing wrong?

```
2011-08-05T07:36:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-08-05T07:36:01+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-08-05T07:36:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-08-05T07:36:02+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-08-05T07:36:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-08-05T07:36:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 48395 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb:4:in `<class:Asset>': uninitialized constant Ckeditor::Orm (NameError)
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/engine.rb:415:in `each'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/engine.rb:415:in `block in eager_load!'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/engine.rb:413:in `each'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/engine.rb:413:in `eager_load!'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block in <module:Finisher>'

:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `new'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `map'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'

8-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-08-05T07:36:13+00:00 heroku[rake.2]: State changed from created to starting

0:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-08-05T07:36:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-08-05T07:36:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-08-05T07:36:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 14622 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-08-05T07:36:17+00:00 app[rake.2]: Awaiting client
2011-08-05T07:36:17+00:00 app[rake.2]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate`
2011-08-05T07:36:19+00:00 heroku[rake.2]: State changed from starting to up
2011-08-05T07:36:21+00:00 heroku[rake.2]: Process exited
2011-08-05T07:36:21+00:00 heroku[rake.2]: State changed from up to complete
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb:4:in `<class:Asset>': uninitialized constant Ckeditor::Orm (NameError)
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/engine.rb:415:in `each'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/engine.rb:415:in `block in eager_load!'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/engine.rb:413:in `each'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/engine.rb:413:in `eager_load!'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `new'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `map'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_

2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2011-08-05T07:36:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-08-05T07:36:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say take a look at line 4 in you app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb file

```
 /app/app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb:4:in `<class:Asset>': uninitialized constant Ckeditor::Orm (NameError)
```

maybe you need to initialize the CK Editor in another way or deactivate it and see if it works then...

edit: [here is another thread on how to make ckeditor work with heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306951/how-to-integrate-ckeditor-with-heroku)

Comment: This is the problem. You need to include this module.