# Problems with ckeditor running on production Rails application with Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor, asset-pipeline, production-environment

I'm using the **ckeditor** gem in my **Rails 4** application.
Everything works great locally and on my staging heroku environment, but I get this errors when pushing on the production environment :

```
GET http://myapp.herokuapp.com/assets/ckeditor/contents.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://myapp.herokuapp.com/assets/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png 404 (Not Found)
```

The editor shows up well, but all icons are missing.

I followed the README (https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor), but I'm probably missing something.

Here are my steps:

1) Gem installation, generate etc ...

2) `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)` in application.js

3) `mount Ckeditor::Engine => "/ckeditor"` in routes.rb (I don't understand why)

4) In application.js

```
//= require ckeditor/override
//= require ckeditor/init
```

What is this doing exactly, why is override needed ? (Where are located these files, because there are not in `/app/assets`, neither in `/lib/assets` neither in `/vendor/assets`)

Heroku is read only oriented, therefore I can't run the rake task as explained in the tutorial.
And I think this is why I get the errors in production mode.

Did anyone faced the same problem ?
I ran through all stackoverflow questions, but nothing resolved my problem so far.

**UPDATE :**

The only way I found out to make it works is the live compilation : `config.assets.compile = true` 
But I would prefer not to use this in production, and I don't understand why it does work.

Comment: have you fixed this somehow? i have same problem, Rails 4 + Ckeditor gem + Ckeditor downloaded from their website, i have done everything in tutorial and i just get 404 (Not Found) in dev tools, is this a problem with routes?

Comment: I didn't have time to try it yet, this is why I didn't accept any answer.

Comment: @Umren got your issue solved? I too have the same problem.

Comment: dunno if readme has been updated (or if you solved your issue) but they added a section to write a rake task that copies non-digested version of ckeditor assets in the proper place. Take a look at that, to me it's working ok, even without adding the path to the precompile.Same as proposed in the link suggested by @felix Ding

Comment: I have this issue too.

Comment: I've the same problem. ckeditor works fine in development but not in production. I tested out everything suggested here and on github :-(((

Answer (score 15):

Currently the solution for this problem has been changed.

There is no need to include "ckeditor/override.js"

1 Update your gem.

```
bundle update ckeditor
```

2 Add this line to your file config/application.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
```

It works for me hope will work for you too.

Comment: it worked! but I don't like the idea of having to precompile.

Comment: This is the solution in my case as well. Rails 5.

Comment: Tried this but not working. also tried `heroku run RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` but still editor is not loading , no error

Answer (score 5):

I just solved this problem following this: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/307#issuecomment-22186377 .

Basically, you add ckeditor asset to the precompile list in `application.rb`, use the rake task to copy them to the proper location during deployment.

Hope it helps.

Comment: actually there's a section also in the readme of the ckeditor gem with the same (working) solution, also to integrate the rake task in capistrano.

Answer (score 4):

I followed the instructions on [GitHub](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/307#issuecomment-22186377)

You need to set with true the following variable in the file **config/enviroments/production.rb**

`config.assets.compile = true`

and add the following code

```
config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
config.assets.precompile += %w(ckeditor/* )
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
```

My environment to this solution was:

> gem 'ckeditor', '~> 4.1'
>
> ruby "2.3.0"
>
> rails 5.0.0.1

Comment: You dont want to have live compiling in production: [why not link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets` in your `application.rb` should do the work.

Comment: It doesn't change anything, even after running a second `rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here are my files and how I fixed:

#### application.js

```
//= require ckeditor/override
//= require ckeditor/init
```

#### Gemfile

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

then run bundle to generate Gemfile.lock and commit files to your repo.

#### production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
config.assets.compile = false # we don't want compilation fallbacks
```

Deploy to heroku and verify it.

Hope that helps somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on application and that works fine in dev env but when i am deploying it to Heroku assets are not loading at all & for that reason i am not able to load TinyMCE or CkEditor js or css.

I found out a work around and compiled assets locally and pushed to Heroku then i got the compiled assests url for CkEditor JS and included it in my view like

```
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

If you wanna load ckeditor assets from cloud u can use CDN like

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.6.2/ckeditor.js"</script>
```

Also u need to change few settings in your production.rb file

```
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
  config.assets.precompile += %w(ckeditor/* )
  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
```

and it starts working on Heroku as well.

For any other issues pls reply.