# Ckeditor not displaying in production Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-5

So I updated Ckeditor to 4.2. After I did this, Ckeditor no longer appears in production. Instead, I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: CKEDITOR.style.customHandlers[e.type] is not a constructor
```

I've consulted a few sources, including this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777316/problems-with-ckeditor-running-on-production-rails-application-with-heroku), which claimed the issue was in precompilation. I've edited my application.rb to include Ckeditor in precompilation, but it still doesn't work.

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)


module DeployTest
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
    config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
    config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
  end
end
```

Weirdly enough, when I turn `config.assets.debug = true`, Ckeditor starts working again, but my CSS turns off.

Why does `config.assets.debug` work? Why does it turn off my CSS? And how can I get a permanent solution for ckeditor?

Answer (score 0):

Using ckeditor gem from git solved this issue for me

gemfile:

```
gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'
```

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/719